# Setting foreign keys at rails, yet record.association_name returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I don't understand why this piece of rspec code is behaving this way. I am setting `product_id` to my record, and it is asserting true, but yet `record.product` returning nil.

```
product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)

post :create, {:tshirt => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:tshirt).stringify_keys.merge("product_id"=> product.id.to_s) } #successful creation
expect(Tshirt.last.product_id).to eq(product.id)  # asserts true

puts Tshirt.last.product #prints nothing
expect(Tshirt.last.product.size).to eq(product.size)  # exception!!! it says, product = nil
```

I have also tried at console, and there it works fine, can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to do a `.reload`?

Comment: yep, I did @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu

Comment: How is the association configured?

Comment: And is product definitely saved correctly (has non nil id)?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that Tshirt class has the association `belongs_to :product`.